# Returning the length of the File in B/KB/MB

Tags: java, performance, file, io, formatting

The method `length()` in `File` returns the length of a file in Bytes, this code transforms that into b/kb/mb as can be seen in the Windows Explorer

I ended up with the code below, let me know if it can be optimized or the logic can be improved.

```
public static String getFileSize(File file) {
    String modifiedFileSize = null;
    double fileSize = 0.0;
    if (file.isFile()) {
        fileSize = (double) file.length();//in Bytes

        if (fileSize < 1024) {
            modifiedFileSize = String.valueOf(fileSize).concat("B");
        } else if (fileSize > 1024 && fileSize < (1024 * 1024)) {
            modifiedFileSize = String.valueOf(Math.round((fileSize / 1024 * 100.0)) / 100.0).concat("KB");
        } else {
            modifiedFileSize = String.valueOf(Math.round((fileSize / (1024 * 1204) * 100.0)) / 100.0).concat("MB");
        }
    } else {
        modifiedFileSize = "Unknown";
    }

    return modifiedFileSize;
}
```

Comment: You might find this interesting- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java/3758880#3758880.

Comment: Your output is incorrect. 1 MB = 1000*1000 bytes. 1 MiB = 1024*1024 bytes.

Comment: i don't know about that here MB = 1204 * 1024 Bytes

Answer (score 7):

## Logic

You can simplify your logic by testing for the biggest known extension, for example

```
if (fileSize > 1024 * 1024)
    doMiB();
} else if (fileSize > 1024) {
    doKiB();
} else {
    doByte();
}
```

## Rounding

Don't use `Math.round(x / 100.0) * 100.` for rounding to two decimal places use [the appropriate library function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12806303/2534648)

## Argument checking

Don't use default values (`"Unknown"`) for invalid input. If the input to your `getFileSize` method is not a file, throw an exception

```
if (!file.isFile()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected argument to be a file");
}
```

## Fast return

This is more personal taste but I prefer to return as soon as possible. If you know the result will be "100.31 KiB" why save it into a local variable instead of returning it immediately?

## Conclusion

I would improve the code as followed

```
private static final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
private static final long MiB = 1024 * 1024;
private static final long KiB = 1024;

public String getFileSize(File file) {

    if (!file.isFile()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected a file");
    }
    final double length = file.length();

    if (length > MiB) {
        return format.format(length / MiB) + " MiB";
    }
    if (length > KiB) {
        return format.format(length / KiB) + " KiB";
    }
    return format.format(length) + " B";
}
```

Comment: @EmilyL. i am actually now in favor of Using `DecimalFormat`

Comment: Thank you @EmilyL. yes OP should use `DecimalFormat` I will update the link

Comment: In addition to these, as a scalable and cleaner way you can make an enum of Units with each having method fromBytes() to convert bytes to target unit.

Comment: There should be a semi-colon after return format.format(length) + " B" I suggested an edit and but it is rejected twice

Comment: @AmarIlindra you are correct, an `;` was missing. I fixed this mistake, don't know why your revisions where rejected

Answer (score 6):

## Use helper functions

The logic performed by your math isn't immediately obvious at a glance. You should introduce a helper function:

```
static double roundToDecimals(double aValue, int aDecimals){
    ...
}
```

Even better, just use `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String output = df.format(1.2345678);  // "1.23"
```

## Work in logarithms

You can simplify your determination of the correct suffix by using the logarithm of the file size.

First of note that \$1024 = 2^{10}\$,  \$1024*1024 = 2^{20}\$ and so forth. You're checking if \$x < 2^{10}\$ and then if \$x < 2^{20}\$ etc.

It's much easier to take the two-logarithm of \$x\$ and then check \$\log_2(x) < 10\$, \$\log_2(x) < 20\$ etc...

Now if you take \$k=floor(\log_2(x) / 10)\$ you will end up with \$k=0\$ for bytes, \$k=1\$ for KiB, \$k=2\$ for MiB etc. Which means that you can simply index into an array of the suffixes to get the right suffix, then upscale the result to get the correct number of digits.

Like this:

```
public static double log2(long n){
    // Implement this but without inaccuracies due to FP math. 
    // Just count the number of leading zeros and do the math.
    return (Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));
}

public static String getFileSize(File file) {
    ...
    long logSize = (long)log2(fileSize);
    final String[] suffixes = new String[]{" B", " KiB", " MiB", " GiB", " TiB", " PiB", " EiB", " ZiB", " YiB"};

    int suffixIndex = (int) (logSize / 10); // 2^10 = 1024

    double displaySize = fileSize / Math.pow(2, suffixIndex*10);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return df.format(displaySize) + suffixes[suffixIndex];
```

## Other comments

You should keep your `fileSize` in `long` format for accuracy.
Also you can move the `fileSize` variable into the scope of the `if` where it is initialized and used.

Comment: @Emily L i need clarification on this


`displaySize = df.format(displaySize);`
Since the `displaySize`is type of `double`
and `df.format(...)` returns `String`???

Comment: @EmilyL. exactly, but the confusion is here `displaySize = df.format(displaySize);`

Comment: **you are assigning String to double???**

and one more thing , What if the File size ==0 ??
i just try a simple Test and the output was this

**File Size = 0
Log Size = -9223372036854775808
suffix Index = 858993460**
which also caused `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Because the the **suffix index was = 85899........**

Comment: @mak By definition \$log(0)=-\infty\$. Just handle the case if `fileSize = 0` specially.

Comment: allright , but what about **displaySize = df.format(displaySize);**

Comment: perfect, one last need i am still confuse what to do if **File Size == 0**

Comment: Will that work?

`if (fileSize==0) {
            suffixIndex = 0;
        }`
Because **0. 0 B == 0 MB == 0 PB**

Comment: @mak I'm not your contractor. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: How rude... any ways its working .... thanks for the Help :D